# ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Azure AD B2C with external Identity Providers auth - invalid_request

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I created a ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app in VS2019 and it uses Azure B2C authentication. And it works **if** I register a user as `Local account`.

Also, I set up Microsoft and Google identity providers. Now, I click on *"Sign In"* link in my app (https://localhost:44396/AzureADB2C/Account/SignIn) and it presents standard Azure B2C auth screen. I click on "Microsoft" (account) and it does some redirect and then shows me:

> invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

Which part is missing in this should-be-simple set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow step 7 again, your redirect uri is incorrect.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account

Go to the App registration you created as part of the setup to federate with Microsoft Accounts.

Go to Authentication, make sure you have Web Platform enabled and a RedirectURI set to `https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`  in the text box. Replace `<tenant-name>` with your Azure AD B2C tenant name.

Comment: I did add that oauth2/resp link in the first place. It didn't work. That's why I posted the question here. I should've included it I guess.

Comment: Your problem is definitely with the reply URL. All lower case?

Comment: Yes! The problem is I have __another__ previously created app for IdP and it has reply url with tenant guid, not the tenant name. I added new reply url and it works! Thanks!